# How to represent aggregated null values as 0 in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

I need to aggregated null value to show as 0 in the output.

You can look at the sql code here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ff1d4/4

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
    CustomerId int PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderId int PRIMARY KEY,     
    CustomerId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customers(CustomerId),
    Amount INT
);

insert into Customers values(1, 'Peter');
insert into Customers values(2, 'Paul');
insert into Customers values(3, 'Mary');

insert into Orders values(1,1,100);
insert into Orders values(2,2,200);
insert into Orders values(3,1,300);

select c.customerid,name,count(orderId) OrderCount, ISNULL(sum(amount),0) TotalAmount 
from customers c 
  JOIN orders o on c.customerid = o.customerid
group by C.customerid,NAME;


customerid  name    OrderCount  TotalAmount
1   Peter   2   400
2   Paul    1   200
```

My output should look like following

```
customerid     name     ordercount   totalamount

 1             peter       2            400
 2             paul        2            400
 3             mary        0            0
```

I am not getting last row with my query

Any help?

Comment: Change your INNER JOIN to a LEFT OUTER JOIN to select ALL records from your customer table and only those records that match from your order table...  and let 'er rip. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ff1d4/6

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the sqlfiddle directly in your post, it's not that much code and everyone has to see it to answer anyway..